# Access Node.js variable from javascript file in front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

Is it possible to access a node.js variable from the backend in a javascript file with pug?

It seems to work when using inline javascript inside the pug template, but I can't get it to work if when link to a .js file.

This is my router:

```
router.get("/test", function (req, res) {
  testVar = {
    title: "Test Title",
    string: "Test string"
  };
  res.render("test", { testVar: testVar });
});
```

My template looks like this:

```
h1 #{testVar.title}

div #{testVar.string}

//- Inline JavaScript works
script. 
    var object = !{JSON.stringify(testVar)};
    console.log(object.title);
    console.log(object.string);

//- This does not work
script(src="/javascripts/test.js")
```

test.js have the same content as the inline javascript:

```
var object = !{JSON.stringify(testVar)};
console.log(object.title);
console.log(object.string);
```

If I try to run it with test.js enabled I get an error saying:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing : after property id
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with `!{JSON.stringify(testVar)}`

JSON.stringify turns your object to a string, then you put it in an object and turn it into a boolean.

So var object isn't an object and you're getting an error when referring to object.id.
You can test this by `console.log(object)` or even `testVar`.

Comment: Is the behavior different in the two javascript's?
`var object = !{JSON.stringify(testVar)};` works in `script .` but not in `test.js`

`console.log(testVar)` returns an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: testVar is not defined` both places.

If i create the object in `script.` with `var object = !{JSON.stringify(testVar)};` I am able to reach it in `test.js`, but this would not work when inheriting from another pug template that does not have access to testVar.

Comment: I might have been going about the inheritance the wrong way. I was originally inheriting my page from my `navbar.pug` template. But I think importing the navbar template makes more sense. I can now at least have `script.` in my test.pug template.
I'm however still not able to take the variable directly in to my js file.